# Convert C++ to Python (For Loop multiple assignment)

Tags: c++, python, for-loop

Convert to python:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = i + 3; i < 100; ++i, j= i+3)
         cout << i << " j: " << j << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I try:

```
for i in range(99):
    j = i + 3
    print i, " j: ", j
```

How to make it one for loop?

Comment: I mean I want to make the python program only 2 lines like the C++ reall tis

Comment: Like 0ne python FOR LOOP to do the same job the C++ for l00p d03s

Comment: It already looks like one loop to me. How many do you see?

Comment: Wow, if this use-case was any more real world, it would be the actual REAL WORLD

Comment: The C++ is way more than two lines. And the idea that code is better because there are fewer lines is misguided.

Comment: If you add another copy of the `j = i + 3` line into your python code, it'll look more like your C++ code.  You should note that your C++ code is two lines, but 87 characters, while your python code is three lines, but only 57, *and* it doesn't repeat itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change 99 to 100

```
for i in range(100):
  j = i + 3
  print i, " j: ", j
```

Or

```
for i,j in [(i, i+3) for i in range(100)]:
```

Comment: @jleedev: Your post was not there when I was typing. So why a downvote?

Comment: I would use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension there, were I to do it this way.

Answer (score 6):

These are identical except for the upper bound in the loop (98 vs 99). What is the question?

On one line (but please don't do this):

```
for i,j in [(i, i+3) for i in range(100)]:
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `j` is always dependent on the value of `i` you may as well replace all instances of `j` with `i + 3`.

Answer (score 3):

I dont get it, it *is* exactly one python `for loop` there. What is the question? Do you want the `j` declaration inside the loop declaration like in c++? Check Prasson'S answer for the closest python equivalent. But why have a j variable in the first place? `j=i+3` seems to always be true, so why not this?

```
for i in range(100):
    print i, " j: ", i+3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i,j) in zip(range(100), range(3, 100+3)):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(100):
    j = i + 3
    print i, "j:", j
raw_input()
```

C++: http://ideone.com/7Kdmk

Python: http://ideone.com/nATEP